# Convert To Decimal an arabic number

Tags: vb.net

I have a numeric entry `Nbr` containing arabic numbers `١٢٣٤٥٦`

My Issue is when I try to use the `Convert.ToDecimal(Nbr)`I receive a notification saying that the input format is wrong (not supported).

Is there any solution that I may use to bypass this problem without converting the Nbr from arabic to standard numbers `(12345)`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better approach but following works. Convert the arabic numbers with [`Char.GetNumericValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getnumericvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to a roman number:

```
Dim arabicNumber = "١٢٣٤٥٦"
Dim romanNumber = From c In arabicNumber Select Char.GetNumericValue(c)
Dim number = string.Concat(romanNumber)
```

Now you can use `Decimal.Parse`:

```
Dim d As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(number)
```

The result with your string `١٢٣٤٥٦` is `123456`.

Comment: Beat me to it! You may want to use this as an `extension method` if you find you will use it often. Its unfortunate the framework doesn't have anything in-built for this, even using `CultureInfo` doesn't work.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yup, I am forced to used each time I have a numeric field :( 
and the problem now is in the sql server :D

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd: why don't you clean your database? You should show arabic numbers only if the user wants to see them so

Comment: @TimSchmelter that is what i am thinking of doing. better keep bold stuff in my Code than Sql too.